# Hover Effect targeting sibling's child pseudo element

Tags: css

Navigation can't be edited directly and the **.active** menu item is swapped out with a `::before` pseudo element.

`.rel a` is an overlay to make it working button, but needs matching hover effect.

For positioning the div.rel is collapsed

```css
li {
  margin: 4px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  height: 30px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

li.active::before {
  content: '4';
}

li.active a {
  visibility: hidden;
}

ul li.active::before {
  background-color: green;
}

div.rel a:hover~ul li.active::before {
  background-color: yellow;
}

div.rel {
  position: relative;
}

div.rel a {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!-- nav code can't be edited -->
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">4</a></li> <!-- <<<<  This 4 needs to turn yellow when you hover the red button -->
</ul>
<!-- nav code can't be edited -->
<div class="rel">
  <a class="overlay" href="#">Hover here turn 4 yellow</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I said "Sibling's child"

Comment: I don't think it's possible without being able to change your markup.